# Per-collection read/write monitoring in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Per the advice of my good friend Mark Z, we're moving fast and breaking things in our app. While doing so, however, I'd rather not blow up our budgets unnecessarily.

Is it possible to track Firestore reads/writes on a per-collection basis? I'm aware that I can track at a high level using the [steps described here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#stackdriver-setup) but I'd like to see more granular data.

Comment: There is currently nothing more detailed than what you've found.